# How to send response from server in nodejs to generate pdf in frontend using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, pdf

Can you anyone suggest me,

I have two cases in the backend for same request. In first case server has to respond in json format and in second case I need to send arraybuffer data in json response. Receiving data in client side is ok, but when I'm trying to print arraybuffer as a pdf in client side, empty document is coming out. Please suggest to this. For the last two days i'm struggling on it.

Comment: This question is **too broad**.

Comment: Sorry .. I cant reduce.

Comment: Share some snippets of the front end and back end code for the ArrayBuffer send and the way you are processing it in Angular and it might be easier to help.